# Exit the entire recursion stack

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm calling a function fooA from main() that calls another function fooB that is recursive. 
When I wish to return, I keep using exit(1) to halt execution. What is the right way to exit when the recursion tree is deep?

Returning through the recursion stack may not be of help because returning usually clears a part solution I build and I don't want to do that. I want to do execute more piece of code from main().

I read Exceptions can be used, it would be nice if I can get a code snippet.

Comment: Post your code. Use `return`s instead of exceptions if possible.

Comment: Return a specific value that means "end everything right now" ? For example, return -1 and add logic to check if the returned value is -1. If that's the case, return -1.

Comment: You could try using goto. Although it's not that good a solution.

Comment: The code runs for 1000 lines. I'll post a short version in a sec. 
@AlexandreP.Levasseur: Seems good, I'll try that.

Comment: @SidR You would need a `longjmp()`. `goto` won't get you out of a stack. But I think `longjmp()` is problematic in C++.

Answer (score 17):

The `goto` statement won't work to hop from one function back to another; Nikos C. is correct that it wouldn't account for releasing the stack frames of each of the calls you've made, so when you got to the function you goto'ed to, the stack pointer would be pointing to the stack frame of the function you were just in... no, that just won't work.  Similarly, you can't simply call (either directly, or indirectly via a function pointer) the function you want to end up in when your algorithm is done.  You'd never get back to the context you were in prior to diving into your recursive algorithm.  You could conceivably architect a system this way, but in essence each time you did this you'd "leak" what was currently on the stack (not quite the same as leaking heap memory, but a similar effect).  And if you were deep into a highly recursive algorithm, that could be a lot of "leaked" stack space.

No, you need to somehow return back to the calling context.  There are only three ways to do so in C++:

1. Exit each function in turn by returning from it to its caller
   backing up through the call chain in an orderly fashion.
2. Throw an exception and catch it at the point right after you
   launched into your recursive algorithm (which automatically destroys
   any objects created by each function on the stack in an orderly
   fashion).
3. Use setjmp() & longjmp() to do something similar to throwing &
   catching an exception, but "throwing" a longjmp() will not destroy
   objects on the stack; if any such objects own heap allocations,
   those allocations will be leaked.

To do option 1, you have to write your recursive function such that once a solution is reached, it returns some sort of indication that it's complete to its caller (which may be the same function), and its caller sees that fact & relays that fact on to its caller by returning to it (which may be the same function), so on and so on, until finally all stack frames of the recursive algorithm are released and you return to whatever function called the first function in the recursive algorithm.

To do option 2, you wrap the call to your recursive algorithm in a `try{...}` and immediately after it you `catch(){...}` the expected thrown object (which could conceivably be the result of the computation, or just some object that lets the caller know "hey, I'm done, you know where to find the result").  Example:

```
try
{
    callMyRecursiveFunction(someArg);
}
catch( whateverTypeYouWantToThrow& result )
{
    ...do whatever you want to do with the result,
    including copy it to somewhere else...
}
```

...and in your recursive function, when you finish the results, you simply:

```
throw(whateverTypeYouWantToThrow(anyArgsItsConstructorNeeds));
```

To do option 3...

```
#include <setjmp.h>
static jmp_buf jmp; // could be allocated other ways; the longjmp() user just needs to have access to it.
    .
    .
    .
if (!setjmp(jmp)) // setjmp() returns zero 1st time, or whatever int value you send back to it with longjmp()
{
    callMyRecursiveFunction(someArg);
}
```

...and in your recursive function, when you finish the results, you simply:

```
longjmp(jmp, 1); // this passes 1 back to the setjmp().  If your result is an int, you
                 // could pass that back to setjmp(), but you can't pass zero back.
```

The bad thing about using setjmp()/longjmp() is that if there are any stack-allocated objects still "alive" on the stack when you call longjmp(), execution will jump back to the setjmp() point, skipping the destructors for those objects.  If your algorithm uses only POD types, that's not an issue.  It's also not an issue if the non-POD types your algorithm uses do NOT contain any heap allocations (e.g. from `malloc()` or `new`).  If your algorithm uses non-POD types that contain heap allocations, then you're only safe with options 1 & 2 above.  But if your algorithm meets the criteria of being OK with setjmp()/longjmp(), and if your algorithm is buried under a ton of recursive calls at the point it finishes, setjmp()/longjmp() may be the fastest way back to the initial calling context.  If that won't work, option 1 is probably your best bet in terms of speed.  Option 2 may seem convenient (and would possibly eliminate a condition check at the start of each recursion call), but the overhead associated with the system automatically unwinding the callstack is somewhat significant.

It's typically said you should reserve exceptions for "exceptional events" (events expected to be very rare), and the overhead associated with unwinding the callstack is why.  Older compilers used something akin to setjmp()/longjmp() to implement exceptions (setjmp() at the location of the `try` & `catch`, and longjmp() at the location of a `throw`), but there was of course extra overhead associated with determining what objects on the stack need destroyed, even if there are no such objects.  Plus, every time you'd run across a `try`, it would have to save the context *just in case* there was a `throw`, and if exceptions are truly exceptional events, the time spent saving that context was simply wasted.  Newer compilers are now more likely to use what are known as "Zero Cost Exceptions" (a.k.a. Table Based Exceptions), which seems like that would solve all the world's problems, but it doesn't.... It makes normal runtime faster because there is no longer a need to save the context every time you run across a `try`, but in the event that a `throw` executes, there is now *even more overhead* associated with decoding information stored in massive tables that the runtime has to process in order to figure out how to unwind the stack based on the location where the `throw` was encountered and content of the runtime stack.  So exceptions aren't free, even though they're very convenient.  You'll find a lot of stuff on the internet where people make claims about how unreasonably expensive they are and how much they slow down your code, and you'll also find lots of stuff by people refuting those claims, with both sides presenting hard data to bolster their claims.  What you should take away from the arguments is that using exceptions is great if you expect them to rarely occur, because they result in cleaner interfaces & logic that's free of a ton of condition checking for "badness" every time you make a function call.  But you shouldn't use exceptions as a means of normal communication between a caller and its callees, because that mode of communication is significantly more expensive than simply using return values.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me while finding the path from root to node of a binary tree. I was using a stack to store the nodes in preorder and the recursion wouldnt stop until the last node returned NULL. I used a global variable, integer i=1, and when I reached the node I was looking for I set that variable to 0 and used while(i==0) return stack; to allow the program to go back up the memory stack without popping my nodes off.