# How can i jump out some deeply recursed function and return the result directly

Tags: c++, recursion

It's kinda like a search for something. And to make the code clearer to read i wrote the function a recursive one. But problem is when the target is being reached i want to end those deeply recursive functions and return the result directly to the father function.(The one called this function) I know you can use return. But it seems like return can only bring you to the outer function which is still way too far to get to the exit and return the result. Anyone knows how should i do. Thanks

Update:I want to traverse a binary tree to search for a specific node. It's written in C++ and done in a recursive manner. So when job is done i want to jump out directly and return the node pointer rather than return to the outer recursion layer by layer. How could i do. There isn't any code pasted here simply because i can't even figure out how to code, thanks.

2nd Update: Maybe i didn't say it quite clear. Apologize for that. I mean sometimes you just know there is only one node matches in the tree and when that node is reached you just want to return the result to the caller function and not bother to have more recursion. I just wonder if there is some tricks you can bypass the C++ execution mechanism and simply end all the recursions. otherwise you have to return step by step until stack is empty. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is particularly hard to answer without you a) specifying the programming language (use tags please) and b) disclosing the relevant source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exit the entire recursion stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784337/exit-the-entire-recursion-stack)

Comment: What's wrong with returning layer by layer?  If you trust your recursive code, you shouldn't have to do anything special; it should just work automatically.

Comment: Based on your update: Consider *not* complicating your code with non-standard handling of recursion and thus making it less readable, when you are not comfortable about understanding the basics.

Answer (score 1):

If your recursive *definition* is correct to begin with, then everything will just work fine.

Consider this:

```
// Just an example to demonstrate recursion:

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int Size(std::vector<int> const &v)
{
    if (v.empty())
    {
        // size of empty vector = 0
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // size of non-empty vector = 1 + size of sub-vector
        // starting from 2nd element:
        return 1 + Size(std::vector<int>(v.begin() + 1, v.end()));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    std::cout << Size(v) << "\n"; // prints 3
}
```

Perhaps what you really need is a way to handle special error situations where you cannot return normally. In such cases, I've often found exceptions to be a pragmatic solution.

```
int RecursiveFunction(int arg)
{
    // ...

    return RecursiveFunction(/* ... */);

    // ...

    // special error:
    throw std::runtime_error("special error");
}

void StartRecursiveFunction()
{
    try
    {
        int i = RecursiveFunction(start);
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const &exc)
    {
        // error
    }
}
```

Of course, you should not abuse exceptions to return values in the normal program flow.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, return a bool true when you reach the desired node, and a bool false otherwise. Then, in the transversing code, check to see if the search was succesful for each child node before searching the next. If it was, you can return true again, and so on. No extra nodes are searched.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why executing a tree of recursive calls is such a costly operation is because of the width of the tree, not the height. The width increases exponentially where the height is logarithmic.

This means that you can walk back the path from the leaf to the root using returns very easily. For example let's say that you find the result when you reach the 1000000th call. The return chain that retrieves the result back to the top will just be log2(1000000) ~= 20 calls.

You can nontheless use some sort of global data structure to retrieve the result "faster", but it is a very inconsequential faster, and probably not the most elegant and readable solution.