# GOTO instruction in recursive functions

Tags: c++, c

If I use goto instruction inside a recursive function (wanting to exit the function before it finishes naturally) is the stack freed automatically or not?

Comment: Recursive function calls are no different to non-recursive function calls.

Comment: Do you mean going to the return statement?

Comment: Labels are local to a function so you can't exit a function just using `goto`.

Comment: I mean going somewhere in a different function

Comment: No, not to a different function.

Comment: Oh, ok, thx guys, I didn't know that

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13784756/5132337). It will help.

Comment: On Ubuntu 15.10, the default stack size is 8 MBytes.  From this it is highly  unlikely that you would have 1 M returns (a very deep recursion). On my old Dell, it takes ~10 ns to invoke a simple short method. From this I would estimate one can return a value (i.e. true, false, pointer, etc) in less than 1M * 10 ns, or 10 ms.  Are you worried about 10 ms?  Or have you estimated how deep and complex is your return effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the below program, in which there is a goto statement for final return. Will that free the stack just by seeing goto. So even though you use goto inside functions stack will be maintained as such.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fact(int a)
{   
    if(a==1)
        goto A;
    return a*fact(a-1);
    A: return a;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d",fact(10));
}
```

You can't jump from one function to another using goto in Standard C++. From $6.6.4/1 of the C++ Language Standard

> The goto statement unconditionally transfers control to the statement
>   labeled by the identifier. The identifier shall be a label (6.1)
>   located in the current function.

...or in Standard C. From $6.8.6.1/1 of the C Language Standard

> The identifier in a goto statement shall name a label located
>   somewhere in the enclosing function. A goto statement shall not jump
>   from outside the scope of an identifier having a variably modified
>   type to inside the scope of that identifier.

Answer (score 1):

no, and so far as I know most compilers will not goto to exit the current function.

if you must escape directly from deep recursion`throw` an `exception` (c++) or use `longjmp` (c)  these actions will restore the stack.